# Get the state of a Switch in onCreate()

Tags: java, android

So my question is how I can get the state of a Switch.

I have this Code:

```
   notificationSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(notificationSwitch.isChecked()){
                System.out.println("Checked");
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("value", true);
                editor.apply();
                notificationSwitch.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                System.out.println("not checked");
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("value", false);
                editor.apply();
                notificationSwitch.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

The state of the switch is saved in the Shared Preferences and if I start the app the Switch is on the same state as when I left the app. But when I start the app is should print checked or not checked but it doesn't print out anything

Comment: What do you mean `if I start the app` and `if I restart the app`?

Comment: if I start the app is means when i click on the app and restart means when I exit the app and the click on the app again

Comment: Your code is in a click listener so nothing will happen when the app starts or restarts. You have to click the button that the listener has been added to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer based on the title:

To get the state of the switch in onCreate():

```
//in onCreate:

SharedPreferences prefrences = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
//false mean if not found set to false as default
boolean stateSwitch = prefrences.getBoolean("value",false);



//set state for switch
notificationSwitch.setChecked(stateSwitch);

//log the state
if(stateSwitch == true){
    Log.d("TAG","checked");
}else{
    Log.d("TAG","not checked");
}
```

**UPDATE**

- keep your onclicklistener the same, and add the code I provided before your onclicklistener in onCreate:

1) when you turn switch on and leave activity and come back it must stay on.

2) when you turn switch off and leave activity and come back it must stay off.

3) if you do nothing leave activity and come back it must stay off.

Comment: @private432 I showed you in the code how to do exactly that.

Comment: @private432 paste the code in onCreate and see what happens.

Comment: @private432 click the switch and leave and come back and it should remain ON.

Comment: And if i come back to the app and the switch is on it should print on the console checked as I mentioned in my question. And if the switch is off it should print on the console not checked. Currently my app is doing nothing of both options.